# How to retrieve all MySQL settings?

Tags: mysql, configuration, mysql5.5, mysql5.1

I have a configured MySQL server (MySQL 5.1.47-community) that works perfect. I installed a second server (MySQL 5.5.15-community) to see if the new version of MySQL would work with my application before upgrading.

When I run the application against the new server it behaves different. When I run it against the old server (MySQL 5.1.47-community) everything works perfect.

I remember that I set some parameters through the MySQL prompt to accept larger result set and some other stuff, now I can't remember what I did.

So my question is: Is there a way to transfer all the MySQL settings from one server to another?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the output of 'show variables' on both mysql servers.  5.5 is going to have new features and different defaults than a 5.1 setup.  I would recommend putting each set of settings into a file, comparing with diff, and looking for smoking gun(s).